# Can you commit incest?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I want to know if you can have the offspring mate with one of his or her own parents. It's odd, yes, but I'm curious if Bethesda thought this through.

Edit: I'm going to cross breed, by this I mean like this

```
Parent 1 + Parent 2   Parent 3 + Parent 4
    = Child 1            = Child 2

Parent 1 + Child 2    Parent 2 + Child 3
    = Child 3            = Child 4
```

I hope this visual (somewhat) representation will show what I'm planning to do.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty simple thing to try.

Comment: Kids grow in 3 hours, and no one ever seems to die of old age. I wouldn't overthink this.

Comment: I but spaces in between but it didn't work... Sigh

Comment: "Can you..." is an easy question to ask, but "Should you..." might be more important with this question...

Answer (score 14):

I believe there is actually a catch regarding parents/children.  Instead of flirting, when you put them in the same residence the characters remark about "how nice it is to spend time with family".   I am not sure how it affects subsequent generations though!

Comment: I have caught this too, I was very happy to see that happen!

Comment: This is indeed the case. I had a guy and girl in a room for freaking ever as they were a good pair and no smillies! I thought maybe it was the religous outfit the guy was wearing but when another girl was added to the mix they had no issues.. I zoomed in and they are both happy to be with family... Oi! So much time wasted by not zooming in.

Answer (score 5):

Putting two dwellers who were both born of the same two dwellers (ie siblings) in the living quarters will also give the "nice to spend time with family" message. So while you can almost definitely mate half-brothers/sisters, direct siblings are still counted as "family" and they won't reproduce.

Answer (score 4):

You can't mate full- or half-siblings - if a pair of dwellers shares even one parent, they will not mate. You can't mate parents to their children. You CAN mate grandparents to grandchildren, aunts/uncles to nieces/nephews, cousins to cousins, etc. In other words, the game won't let you mate first-degree relatives, but everything else is fair game. Source: experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

Well I've already tried it and the children were just normal as all others.

Comment: What do you mean by 'were just normal as all others'? Will they breed or will they not?

Comment: They produce baby's as all other people would do in the barracks. :-) And the baby's are normal too.

Comment: Oddly, they're all automatically given the last name of Lannister.

Comment: @Sterno Is this true? That would be one hell of an Easter Egg :D

Comment: Well I haven't noticed that. But I should say that I haven't an eye on that as I'm not a GoT fan. :-D

Comment: I may have been joking.

Comment: What? Never! We'll I have noticed it - never mind. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have just found out that breeding can occur between a Great Grand Child and their Great Grand Parent.  This means that with a restriction of only three of one sex technically a quite disturbed Lannister cycle can be formed!