# Family dweller?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I had the weirdest thing; I tried to get a dwellar pregnant but it just wouldn't happen. (both male and female had very high charm). When I zoomed in on the living quarters they kept saying (I'm paraphrasing a bit): "There's nothing like staying at home with family".

I switched the male for a different male and the female was pregnant in under a minute.

Odd, I didn't realize being family was a feature. What purpose does it serve?

Btw: I never bother changing any of the dwellers names, so they had their original generated name, and they weren't the same last names.

**Update**: The "Can you commit incest" question is sort of similar to mine, but I am still curious as to which purpose it serves, it it moral? It's basically a huge swing fest already anyway.

Comment: The children always get their dad's family name, they still might be related if they have a different dad but same mom.

Comment: I see. Do you have any idea why the game bothers tracking the sibling and ancestry?

Comment: Probably to avoid some [weird minded people](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/224031/can-you-commit-incest) to try it. Also it would make more sense that way.

Comment: The family tracking is very basic - I believe it only applies to direct parents

Comment: I thought children got the name of the parent with the same gender, so daughter's got mother's surname.

Comment: "I am still curious as to which purpose it serves" - that's basically up to the developers. We can't know for sure, so we can't answer this question

Comment: They *usually* get the surname of their father, but *sometimes* of their mother. @JonathanDrapeau

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no relation between them. Maybe just a bug. My barracks are really breeder rooms. There was one woman and a man at the start. Currently the both named dwellers + 2 of their children are nearly permanently in those room together and are nearly permanently pregnant.

I've had a similar problem for a time, but after closing and restarting (and waiting some minutes) she gets pregnant by her son. ^^

So I'm pretty sure there is no relation between it. On the other hand I've seen this relation too as there was a dweller and someone in the badlands who came together in one room. They said the same thing to each other, even if they are obviously not from the same family.